# Android Button click on Fragment no works

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, onclicklistener

when I trying click on a button no works, the app, keeps alive but no makes anything it's a fragment.
Help Please!

My code is here:

myfragment.xml

```
<TableRow> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"/>
</TableRow>
```

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Tittle");
    }
    android.widget.Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.hello);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.hello:
            android.util.Log.i("mylog", "Pressed");
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

and change:

```
android.widget.Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.hello);
```

to:

```
Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.hello);
```

Comment: Congratulations on founding the bug! Now you can close the question by set your answer as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [**`setOnClickListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) functionality respect to **`TableRow`**.

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/_tableROW"> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"/>
</TableRow>
```

**Example**

```
TableRow _tableROWOBJ = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id._tableROW);
_tableROWOBJ.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your CODE
    } 
});
```

**EDIT**

Use **Button** instead of **`android.widget.Button`**.

Comment: Please, don't steal the op answer and integrate it to yours. Don't encourage unfairness.